# Can't connect to Astra DB with Python driver

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-astra, cassandra-driver, cassandra-python-driver

I believe I'm doing exactly as mentioned in the documentation [Python-driver-AstraDB](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/getting-started/gs-drivers.html)

```
cloud_config= {
        'secure_connect_bundle': 'secure-connect-test-warehouse.zip'
}

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(my_id, my_secret)
cluster = Cluster(cloud=cloud_config, auth_provider=auth_provider)
session = cluster.connect()

row = session.execute("select release_version from system.local").one()
if row:
    print(row[0])
else:
    print("An error occurred.")
```

I get the following error :

```
File "connect_database.py", line 23, in <module>
    session = cluster.connect()
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1677, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1713, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1700, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3507, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection.connect
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3552, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection._reconnect_internal
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers
OSError(101, "Tried connecting to [('...', ..., 0, 0)]. Last error: Network is unreachable")})
```

I suspect `Network is unreachable` has to do with network latency I tried to set `Cluster(cloud=cloud_config, auth_provider=auth_provider,control_connection_timeout=10)` default of control_connection_timeout is 2.0, yet I get the same issue.

if correct how can I solve this ?

Comment: Can you get the secure bundle to work with another application or even cqlsh (standalone from Cassandra, not cqlsh in Astra)?  Also, is the database hibernated?  That actually may throw a different error, but definitely worth checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says to use the ***absolute path of the Secure Connect Bundle (SCB)*** as follows,

```
cloud_config= {
        'secure_connect_bundle': '/path/to/secure-connect-database_name.zip'
}
```

> **NOTE:** Set the *cloud_config* parameter for the Cluster initialization as shown in the following example. The secure_connect_bundle must include the absolute path to your Astra DB database credentials (secure-connect-database_name.zip).

In which case, your code should look as below,

```
...
cloud_config= {
        'secure_connect_bundle': '/your_path/to/secure-connect-test-warehouse.zip'
}
...
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your response, yet in spite of specifying the absolute path, I get the same error, here is the full it :                                                                                              `OSError(101, "Tried connecting to [('2c0f:fa18:0:10::224c:68c', 29042, 0, 0)]. Last error: Network is unreachable")` what are the possible issues causing this ?

Comment: Sorry for that. Did you try to do a simple ping test to the IPs/hosts in question from the machine from your are trying to run this?